# Why isn't my popup confirm disclaimer box event listener not being attached to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to make a popup confirm box for a disclaimer when you are leaving my php site. I have been struggling with why the code won't work for over a week now and finally I have decided to see if anyone can help with my problem

So far to test the code, I made a test page to determine if the code worked and I was successful in testing the code on the test page. When I linked the proper script and stylesheet to my php site, the code did not work. I used the inspector to see if I could discover the issue, but the click event listener for the script was not being displayed on any elements the listener should've been on.

Whenever you click on a link, `$('a').click(function ()` this will call the `Confirm` function which in turn should open the confirm box, but instead this event listener is not even being displayed in the inspector. The code was have ESLint errors in brackets before but once I add `/* eslint-env browser */ /* global $ */` the errors stopped happening. I have reached the end of my line on why this could possibly be happening.

```js
/* eslint-env browser */ 
/* global $ */
function Confirm(title, msg, $true, $false, $link) { /*change*/
    var $content =  "<div class='dialog-ovelay'>" +
                        "<div class='dialog'><header>" +
                         " <h3> " + title + " </h3> " +
                         "<i class='fa fa-close'></i>" +
                     "</header>" +
                     "<div class='dialog-msg'>" +
                         " <p> " + msg + " </p> " +
                     "</div>" +
                     "<footer>" +
                         "<div class='controls'>" +
                             " <button class='button button-danger doAction'>" + $true + "</button> " +
                             " <button class='button button-default cancelAction'>" + $false + "</button> " +
                         "</div>" +
                     "</footer>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>";
    $('body').prepend($content);

    $('.doAction').click(function () {
        window.open($link, "_blank"); /*new*/
        $(this).parents('.dialog-ovelay').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    $('.cancelAction, .fa-close').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.dialog-ovelay').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });     
}

$('a').click(function () {
    Confirm('Go to Google', 'Are you sure you want to visit Google', 'Yes', 'Cancel', "https://www.google.com.eg"); /*change*/
});
```

```css
.dialog-ovelay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    z-index: 999999
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog header {
    padding: 10px 8px;
    background-color: #f6f7f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog header h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #555;
    display: inline-block
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog header .fa-close {
    float: right;
    color: #c4c5c7;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    padding: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 1px    
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog header .fa-close:hover {
    color: #b9b9b9
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog header .fa-close:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #673AB7;
    color: #a2a2a2
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog .dialog-msg {
    padding: 12px 10px
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog .dialog-msg p{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding: 8px 10px
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog footer .controls {
    direction: rtl
}
.dialog-ovelay .dialog footer .controls .button {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 3px
}
.button {
  cursor: pointer
}
.button-default {
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);
    color: #5D5D5D;
}
.button-danger {
    background-color: #f44336;
    border: 1px solid #d32f2f;
    color: #f5f5f5
}
.link {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:php]?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] (the HTML is missing!). Use the [live demo feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of the question editor.

Comment: JavaScript convention dictates that function names starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructor functions / classes, and variable names starting with a $ are reserved for jQuery objects. You should rename your variables to make the code clearer.

Comment: You might find it easier to write your HTML using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which support new lines and variable interpolation.

Comment: also try using `$(document).on()`, eg:  `$(document).on("click", "#my_link", function() {  some_function();  } );`.

Answer (score -1):

**Hello there**
You need to use the confirm as boolean i.e.

```
var userInput = Confirm('Go to Google', 'Are you sure you want to visit Google', 'Yes', 'Cancel');
if(userInput) {
    window.open("https://www.google.com.eg");
}
```

Try it and let me know.

Comment: The `Confirm` function has no `return` statement, so it will **always** return `undefined`.